# Why my uninstalled jdk version still shows in java -version?

Tags: java, java-8

In my project which need jdk 1.8, but there is default openjdk 17 in my mac. So I remove it from `Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`. But when I run java -version it still shows my default jdk version is openjdk 17. And when I run `/usr/libexec/java_home`it shows `/Users/lidu/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-17/Contents/Home`. But I am sure that there isn't a directory called `openjdk-17` in the path `/Users/lidu/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`.

And when I run  `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v "1.8.0_331")`it can be changed to jdk 1.8 but in the next time when I create a new terminal, it still shows the default jdk version is open jdk 17.

Answer (score 3):

export will only persist in the terminal, if you run it manually.

Add the export JAVA_HOME command in .profile file at home directory, so that it will persist in every newly created terminal.

Comment: Thank you! But I have add export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8 in the User/.bash_profile but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Did to try adding it in .profile

Comment: Yes! I add the following in .prifile: export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_331.jdk/Contents/Home 
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH. But when I create a new session it still shows openJDK 17.

Comment: Add it in .zshrc as well & see